# Button Initialization

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie javascript programmer and I'm having trouble with my codes. Well actually, I'm not the one who created this code. Our main job is to debug and make this code work.

This code is for a button that should be disabled at the beginning. This is working for IE but it doesn't seem to work on Firefox, I don't know what's the problem and I would appreciate it if you could help me on this one.

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (btnList.item(i).id != targetButtonId) {
        // 押下：可／不可
        btnList.item(i).disabled = !enable;
        // ボタンイメージ：通常表示／半透明
        if (document.all) {
            // IE
            btnList.item(i).style.filter = (enable ? '1' : 'Alpha(Opacity=50)');
        } else {
            // FF
            btnList.item(i).style.opacity = (enable ? '1' : '.5');
        }
    }
}
```

***EDIT: here's the code for it (yes it's in japanese sorry) :(

```
setEnableForDrawing: function(enable) {

    var layout = this.getToolbar();

    // 設定／解除指示回数チェック
    if (enable) {
        lock4setEnableForDrawing--;
        if (0 < lock4setEnableForDrawing) return;
    } else {
        lock4setEnableForDrawing++;
        if (1 < lock4setEnableForDrawing) return;
    }

    if (layout && 
        layout.regions) {

        // メニューバー
        if (layout.regions.north && 
            layout.regions.north.el) {

            if (enable) {
                layout.regions.north.el.unmask();
            } else {
                layout.regions.north.el.mask();
            }  
        }

        // ツールバー
        if (layout.regions.center && 
            layout.regions.center.bodyEl.dom && 
            layout.regions.center.bodyEl.dom.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')) {

            var btnList = layout.regions.center.bodyEl.dom.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
            var length = btnList.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                if (btnList.item(i).id != 'tool_move_drag'       && // 掴み
                    btnList.item(i).id != 'tool_move_center'     && // 中心
                    btnList.item(i).id != 'tool_zoom_rect'       && // 矩形                        
                    btnList.item(i).id != 'tool_zoom_in'         && // 拡大
                    btnList.item(i).id != 'tool_zoom_out'        && // 縮小
                    btnList.item(i).id != 'tool_emph') {            // 解除

                    // 押下：可／不可
                    btnList.item(i).disabled = !enable;
                    // ボタンイメージ：通常表示／半透明
                    if (document.all) {
                        // IE
                        btnList.item(i).style.filter = (enable ? '' : 'Alpha(Opacity=50)');
                    } else {
                        // FF
                        btnList.item(i).style.opacity = (enable ? '1' : '.50');
                    }
                }

            } // end of for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        } // end of ツールバー側制御

    }
}, // end of setEnableForDrawing()
```

Comment: @isherwood things that are not in English are commented out. Why do you need them ?

Comment: I'd think that would be apparent--comments serve a purpose or they're wasted bytes.

Comment: I'm not the one who made these, so I can't just opt them out entirely. I'm still stuck to this problem though.

Comment: Please include the error message from the console, otherwise this question isn't useful for future vistiors.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the b :)

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (btnList.item(i).id != targetButtonId) {
        // 押下：可／不可
        btnList.item(i).disabled = !enable;
        // ボタンイメージ：通常表示／半透明
        if (document.all) {
            // IE
            btnList.item(i).style.filter = (enable ? '1' : 'Alpha(Opacity=50)');
        } else {
            // FF
            **b**tnList.item(i).style.opacity = (enable ? '1' : '.5');
        }
    }
}
```

Tracked the issue: firefox has a document.all variable: [object HTML document.all class]
so that's why it also works for FF. A fix under this txt, if it returns -1 then it means it isen't ie, cheers mate.

```
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
// Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
// (indicating the use of another browser).
{
  var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
  {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
  }
  return rv;
}
```

Comment: it's there dont worry, i just erased it when i pasted the codes. and the problem still remains :(

Comment: I think this has something to do with this part:
btnList.item(i).disabled = !enable;

Comment: Um is the var enabeld defined by you ?

Comment: setEnableForDrawing: function(enable) {

Comment: Could you please post the entire code would be alot easier to track down bugs that way :). Did you check if firefox has document.all btw ?  Maybe a more recent version has this.

Comment: I've edited the post so you could see. :)

Comment: Specifically, we need to know how the variable "enable" is set. Is it set to a true boolean value, or does it merely evaluate to a boolean?

Comment: the variable "enable" is automatically set to bool. When you call that function, it gives a boolean parameter.